# Web Scrape to Google Sheets

Tags: google-chrome, google-apps-script, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am rather new to the coding world and thank everyone who contributed, you all are helping shape the world into an advanced era that will better the future. I was wondering if it is even possible at the current moment to create a script or app that web scrapes and adds certain areas of a website to a google sheet. I own the website and it allows users to automatically make submissions. Essentially, I want to track any new submissions to the sight and add them to a google sheet, which I use with my team to collaborate and edit those new submissions. We have a current spreadsheet, however, manually each day I need to go in the website and add to the sheet all new submissions of the day. If there is any way to automate this process, insights, or a forum post out there I will appreciate it!

Comment: I think that about retrieving values from the site, you can use [UrlFetchApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app) for the script and/or might be able to use [IMPORTXML](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093342?hl=en) for Spreadsheet. And also I think that about posting values to the server, the method is different by the specification of the server. When you provide your latest script, it will help users think of your solution. If these information were not useful for your situation, I'm sorry.

Comment: If you own the site as you claim then you or your developer can integrate natively  with the google-sheets-api (on the backend)... no need for web scraping.

Comment: You can also put an Apps Script Web App directly into any website in an `<iframe>` tag.  Or you can embed a Google Form in a website, and the Google Form can be linked to a Sheet, no programming needed.